# cordova build 3.6.3 error

Tags: android, cordova, command-line-interface

After update cordova to 3.6.3 when I do **cordova build** I get this error:

```
H:\Android\Workspace\its>cordova build

Running command: H:\Android\Workspace\its\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat


H:\Android\Workspace\its\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'H:\Tizen\Dodatki\adt-bundle-windows-x8
6-20140702\tools\lib\build.template'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:438:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:289:15)
    at H:\Android\Workspace\its\platforms\android\cordova\lib\build.js:93:40
    at _fulfilled (H:\Android\Workspace\its\platforms\android\cordova\node_mo
dules\q\q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (H:\Android\Workspace\its\platforms\android\
cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (H:\Android\Workspace\its\platforms\an
droid\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:760:13)
    at H:\Android\Workspace\its\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js
:574:44
    at flush (H:\Android\Workspace\its\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules
\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
Error: H:\Android\Workspace\its\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command
failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Mix\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

I try reinstall and install and nothing help....any suggestions ?

This directory exists:

> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
>   'H:\Tizen\Dodatki\adt-bundle-windows-x8
>   6-20140702\tools\lib\build.template'

**SOLUTION:**

set ANDROID_HOME to H:\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\platform-tools;

remember at the end add **;**

Comment: Did you add the Tizen platform? Why is it trying to access `H:\Tizen\...`?

Comment: No this is only my catalog name :) not Tizen platform.

When I use cordova 3.5.1 everything works OK

Comment: Why not post your solution as an answer to your question?